# Using conan and CMake with vscode

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I want to start my first C++ project using CMake and Conan.  I'm developing in vscode.  This is the first proper C++ project I've embarked on and I'm trying to be smart about it, but that is hard when your ignorant.  I'm very use to Python virtual environments for development and transitioning to C++ has been a headache.

My CMakeLists.txt is as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(dgp_cpp)

find_package(Eigen 3.4.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(Catch2 3.4.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(Autodiff 1.0.3 REQUIRED) # not available with conan. 

add_executable(tests test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)


add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main Eigen3::Eigen)
```

While my conanfile.txt is

```
[requires]
eigen/3.4.0
catch2/3.4.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

In my project directory, I ran the following command in an activated Python environment where I installed conan using Pip (per their instructions):
`conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing`.

This populated my `build` folder with a bunch of stuff, but the CMake configuration file says it cannot find Eigen or catch2.  My initial thought was that I need to somehow run vscode through the same virtual environment I installed conan, but I have no idea how to do that, or if that even makes sense.

I just hate the idea of using system C++ library installs for development.  It seems like a disaster waiting to happen and is why I hoped C++ would have something closer to Python virtual environments.  Maybe I just need to suck it up and download external libraries to specific folder in the project?

Comment: Probably you are missing the toolchain file path when running cmake command. Please, follow the official tutorial that fits exactly your case: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Comment: That was the tutorial I was using to try and implement this.  I'll go through it another time!

Comment: @cluelessness what is the cmake command that you are running? What you could do is running `cmake --preset=conan-default` and see if this is working